# iPhone draw line with anchor points

Tags: iphone, drawing

I need to create a simple drawing app. This app consists of a line with two anchor points, one at each end. The user should have the ability to touch down on an anchor point and drag it to manipulate the line's length and slope. Also the user should be able to touch down on the line connecting the two anchor points to move it and the anchor points around the screen.

I'm kind of stumped here, I know that I could probably do the manipulation of the length and slope by simply using touch down/up but I do not think this will work for multiple lines?! Can anyone point me in the direction I should be looking please? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I rewrote the answer, this time by implementing a short test. The source code below does the following: On a touch down, it checks the distance of every point inside the list `self.lineDrawView.lines` to the current touch point. If the distance is below 10 px, the current touch point and its list index is saved.

If no matching point is found, another function iterates through all lines made up from pairs inside `self.lineDrawView.lines` and calculates the distance to each line (distance  to line code borrowed [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?194400-Distance-between-point-and-line-segment/page2)). Again, if the distance is below 10 px, the current touch point as well as the starting and ending point of the current line are saved.

Then, on a touch move, either the saved point is moved or the saved line is recalculated by the distance between the previous touch down point and the current touch position.

Header of your view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    CGPoint dragStartingPoint, lineOriginStart, lineOriginEnd;
    int currentPointIndex, currentLineIndex;
}

@property (retain) myView *lineDrawView;
@property (retain) UITouch *currentTouch;
@end
```

Source of your view controller:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.lineDrawView = [[myView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.lineDrawView];
    self.lineDrawView.lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.lineDrawView.lines addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake( 10,  10)]];
    [self.lineDrawView.lines addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(300, 100)]];
    [self.lineDrawView.lines addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200, 400)]];
    [self.lineDrawView.lines addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake( 50, 300)]];
}

-(float)distanceOfPoint:(CGPoint)p toLineWith:(CGPoint)v0 and:(CGPoint)v1
{
    float vx = v0.x - p.x;
    float vy = v0.y - p.y;
    float ux = v1.x - v0.x;
    float uy = v1.y - v0.y;
    float length = ux * ux + uy * uy;
    float result;

    float det = (-vx * ux) + (-vy * uy);
    // if this is < 0 or > length then it's outside the line segment
    if(det < 0)
        result = (v0.x - p.x) * (v0.x - p.x) + (v0.y - p.y) * (v0.y - p.y);
    else if(det > length)
        result = (v1.x - p.x) * (v1.x - p.x) + (v1.y - p.y) * (v1.y - p.y);
    else
    {
        det = ux * vy - uy * vx;
        result = (det * det) / length;
    }

    return sqrtf(result);
}

-(int)getLineNearToPoint:(CGPoint)p withMaximumDistance:(float)d
{
    CGPoint p1, p2;
    NSValue *v1, *v2;

    for(int i=0; i<self.lineDrawView.lines.count/2; i++)
    {
        v1 = [self.lineDrawView.lines objectAtIndex:i*2+0];
        v2 = [self.lineDrawView.lines objectAtIndex:i*2+1];
        p1 = [v1 CGPointValue];
        p2 = [v2 CGPointValue];
        if([self distanceOfPoint:p toLineWith:p1 and:p2]<=d) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

-(int)getPointNearToPoint:(CGPoint)p withinRadius:(float)r
{
    float dx, dy;
    CGPoint p2;
    NSValue *v;

    for(int i=0; i<self.lineDrawView.lines.count; i++)
    {
        v = [self.lineDrawView.lines objectAtIndex:i];
        p2 = [v CGPointValue];
        dx = p.x - p2.x;
        dy = p.y - p2.y;
        if(sqrtf(dx*dx + dy*dy)<=r) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    int iPoint, iLine;
    currentLineIndex = -1;
    currentPointIndex = -1;

    for(UITouch *t in touches)
    {
        // check if a starting/ending point is near the current touch
        CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self.view];
        iPoint = [self getPointNearToPoint:p withinRadius:10];
        if(iPoint != -1)
        {
            currentPointIndex = iPoint;
            self.currentTouch = t;
        }

        // check if current touch is near a line
        iLine = [self getLineNearToPoint:p withMaximumDistance:10];
        if((iLine != -1) && (iPoint == -1))
        {
            currentLineIndex = iLine;
            self.currentTouch = t;

            // save current touch position
            dragStartingPoint = p;

            // save original starting/ending point
            NSValue *v1 = [self.lineDrawView.lines objectAtIndex:iLine*2+0];
            NSValue *v2 = [self.lineDrawView.lines objectAtIndex:iLine*2+1];
            lineOriginStart = [v1 CGPointValue];
            lineOriginEnd = [v2 CGPointValue];
        }

        // only use first touch, discard the rest
        break;
    }
    [self.lineDrawView setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for(UITouch *t in touches)
    {
        // only respond to touch move events of the touch previously assigned
        // to a point or line
        if(t != self.currentTouch) continue;

        CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self.view];

        // Are we moving a starting/ending point?
        if(currentPointIndex != -1)
        {
            NSValue *v = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p];
            [self.lineDrawView.lines replaceObjectAtIndex:currentPointIndex withObject:v];
        }

        // Are we moving a line?
        if(currentLineIndex != -1)
        {
            // calculate drag distance
            float dx = p.x - dragStartingPoint.x;
            float dy = p.y - dragStartingPoint.y;

            // calculate new starting/ending points
            CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(lineOriginStart.x+dx, lineOriginStart.y+dy);
            CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(lineOriginEnd.x+dx, lineOriginEnd.y+dy);
            NSValue *v1 = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p1];
            NSValue *v2 = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p2];

            // replace old values
            [self.lineDrawView.lines replaceObjectAtIndex:currentLineIndex*2+0 withObject:v1];
            [self.lineDrawView.lines replaceObjectAtIndex:currentLineIndex*2+1 withObject:v2];
        }

        // only use first touch, discard the rest
        break;
    }
    [self.lineDrawView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.lineDrawView.lines = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Header of view for drawing:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myView : UIView

@property (retain) NSMutableArray *lines;
@end
```

Source of view for drawing:

```
#import "myView.h"

@implementation myView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // fill background
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.frame);

    // draw lines
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    for(int i=0; i<self.lines.count/2; i++)
    {
        CGPoint p1 = [[self.lines objectAtIndex:i*2+0] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint p2 = [[self.lines objectAtIndex:i*2+1] CGPointValue];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, p1.x, p1.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p2.x, p2.y);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end
```

Comment: Hey nullp01nter, thanks for the suggestion but this does not take into consideration if the touch was the same distance between two points on different lines (if the end of one line overlaps/is near the start of another for example), it also does not tell me if the touch is on a line which I would need to move the line around the screen keeping it's length and slope intact.

Comment: I rewrote my answer since I missed the point with the line movement. The other issue - same distance between two points of different lines - depends on what you want to do in this case. My above solution simply takes the first matching point. You could also search for the nearest point. Equally near points are different, I'm sure you will be able to implement your desired behaviour based on my suggestion above.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort nullp01nter. I have not yet had a chance to test your code but the logic seems sound.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on similar issue and I ended up using UIWebView with something similar to this link

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/splines.html

And I can get the list of the points using

```
[myWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString....]
```

I had to make some changes to the JS code to handle touch start and touch end events instead of mouse down and mouse up to get it to work on the iPad/iPhone

Comment: thanks Mahmoud but I wish to have the solution in Objective C without resorting to Javascript. I upped your answer as I still think its a solution that maybe relevant to others.